# Topology with one element

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

I am asked to prove that a topological space with one element is connected.

My question: I am a little confused by what we mean by a topological space with only one element. Is this sort of equivalent to an indiscrete/ trivial topology? (so an open subset either contains that element or is empty)

Comment: I would read "space with only one element" as the space $X = \{*\}$ with the only topology that it can admit.

Comment: A space with one element is $\{x\}$, with topology $\{\emptyset,\{x\}\}$. Indeed, the trivial and discrete topology are the same on $\{x\}$.

Comment: It is simply $(X, \{\emptyset, X\})$ with $X = \{x\}$

Comment: Okay! Thanks guy. So to prove that it is connected. I simply show that the two open subsets are disjoint (since ∅ intersect {x} is empty), then it follows that if X = {x} u ∅ , either X = {x} or X =∅.

Answer (score 3):

Your last comment does not really make sense. You do not have to show that the open subsets are disjoint, but rather that if $X$ is the union of two disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$, then one of them is  $\emptyset$. In your case, $U$ is either empty, or it is $X$ in which case $V$ must be empty. More generally, this shows that any indiscrete space is connected, and it even works for the empty space $(X,\tau)=(∅,\{∅\})$.

Answer (score 3):

There's another nice characterization of a connected space:

> Let $\mathbf{2}$ be the two point space with the discrete topology.  A topological space $\mathcal{X}=\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is connected iff every continuous function from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathbf{2}$ is constant.

Using this characterization, the result is immediate.